# Pandas Concat dataframes with Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am facing issues in concatenating two Dataframes of different lengths. Below is the issue:

```
    df1 = 
emp_id emp_name counts
1      sam       0
2      joe       0
3      john      0
    
df2 =
emp_id emp_name counts
1      sam       0
2      joe       0
2      joe       1
3      john      0
```

My Expected output is:
Please Note that my expectation is not to merge the 2 dataframes into one but I would like to concat two dataframes side by side and highlight the differences in such a way that, if there is a duplicate row in one df, example df2, the respective row of df1 should show as NaN/blank/None any Null kind of values

```
Expected_output_df = 
df1                      df2    
empId   emp_name counts  emp_id   emp_name  counts
1       sam       0      1        sam       0
2       joe       0      2        joe       0
NaN     NaN       NaN    2        joe       1
3       john      0      3        john      0
```

whereas am getting output as below:

```
actual_output_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis='columns', keys=['df1','df2'])

the above code gives me below mentioned Dataframe. but how can I get the dataframe which is mentioned in the Expected output

actual_output_df = 
df1                      df2    
empId   emp_name counts  emp_id   emp_name  counts
1       sam       0      1        sam       0
2       joe       0      2        joe       0
3       john      0      2        joe       1
NaN     NaN       NaN    3        john      0
```

Tried pd.concat by passing different parameters but not getting expected result.
The main issue I have in concat is, I am not able to move the duplicate rows one row down.

Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: In the above mentioned Problem, the 'counts' column is not necessary for me. I can drop it if required.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/compare-two-dataframes-and-output-their-differences-side-by-side      
This is very similar to what I am looking for except there are no duplicate rows in this example where as I have duplicate rows in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not give the exact output you asked, but it could solve your problem anyway:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['emp_id', 'emp_name', 'counts'], how='outer', indicator=True)
```

Output:

```
    emp_id  emp_name    counts  _merge
0   1       sam         0       both
1   2       joe         0       both
2   3       john        0       both
3   2       joe         1       right_only
```

You don't have rows with NaNs as you wanted, but in this way you can check whether a row is in the left df, right df or both by looking at the `_merge` column. You can also give a custom name to that columns using `indicator='name'`.

---

**Update**

To get the exact output you want you can do the following:

```
output_df = df1.merge(df2, on=['emp_id', 'emp_name', 'counts'], how='outer', indicator=True)

output_df[['emp_id2', 'emp_name2', 'counts2']] = output_df[['emp_id', 'emp_name', 'counts']]

output_df.loc[output_df._merge == 'right_only', ['emp_id', 'emp_name', 'counts']] = np.nan
output_df.loc[output_df._merge == 'left_only', ['emp_id2', 'emp_name2', 'counts2']] = np.nan
output_df = output_df.drop('_merge', axis=1)

output_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('df1', 'emp_id'), ('df1', 'emp_name'), ('df1', 'counts'), 
                     ('df2', 'emp_id'), ('df2', 'emp_name'), ('df2', 'counts')])
```

Output:

```
    df1                         df2
    emp_id  emp_name    counts  emp_id  emp_name    counts
0   1.0     sam         0.0     1.0     sam         0.0
1   2.0     joe         0.0     2.0     joe         0.0
2   3.0     john        0.0     3.0     john        0.0
3   NaN     NaN         NaN     2.0     joe         1.0
```